# ArrayList outside while loop isn't being updated

Tags: java, loops, debugging, arraylist, while-loop

No matter what I try, an `ArrayList<int[]>` I have inside a method defaults to the same value. Using `System.out.println()`s, I was able to find out that the `while` loop inside my method makes changes to the ArrayList, but once it exits the loop, it always defaults to having the array `[0,1,2]`.

Here is the method:

```
private int[][] computeHighestSum() {
    int totalValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    ArrayList<int[]> lowestPositions = new ArrayList<int[]>(); //creates list to hold sequences
    totalValue = (int) graphTraversal(positions)[0]; //assigns default sequence's value
    lowestPositions.add(positions); //adds default sequence to the List

    Object[] x; 
    //loops through and tries other sequences
    while((x = graphTraversal())[1] != null) {
        //if the current sequence produces greater value, clear the List, and then add this sequence, and assign new value to totalValue
        if((int) x[0] > totalValue) {
            lowestPositions.clear();
            totalValue = (int) x[0];
            lowestPositions.add((int[]) x[1]);

        } else if((int) x[0] == totalValue) { 
            lowestPositions.add((int[]) x[1]);
        }
    }
    return lowestPositions.toArray(new int[lowestPositions.size()][]);
}
```

What the method does is initially traverse through a graph and computes a total value, and sets it to the default `totalValue`. Then it adds that particular graph navigation sequence to the `ArrayList<int[]>` which contains the navigation sequences in an `int[]`. This becomes the default `totalValue` and graph sequence.

Then it traverses through the same graph using different sequences until it runs out of valid sequences. If it finds a value that's greater than the current `totalValue`, it assigns that value to `totalValue`, and clears the `ArrayList`, and adds the new sequence. If it finds that it's the same, it adds it to the `ArrayList`.

Inside the `while` loop, it makes changes and everything, but as soon as the method ends, it the ArrayList always contains the same array. Funny thing is, if the `while` loops finds an `n` number of same `totalValue`s, it adds all of them to the `ArrayList` but then at the end of the method, all `n` elements inside the `ArrayList` are the same array: `[0,1,2]`.

Even if I take out the initial `lowestPositions.add(positions);`, which adds the [0,1,2] to begin with, it still defaults to it at the end. The `totalValue` is always computed correctly.

Here is my `System.out.println()` debugging code if it helps:

```
 private int[][] computeHighestSum() {
    int totalValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    ArrayList<int[]> lowestPositions = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    totalValue = (int) graphTraversal(positions)[0];
    lowestPositions.add(positions);
    System.out.println("Default Array added: " + Arrays.toString(positions));
    Object[] x;
    while((x = graphTraversal())[1] != null) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString((int [])x[1]));
        if((int) x[0] > totalValue) {
            lowestPositions.clear();
            totalValue = (int) x[0];
            lowestPositions.add((int[]) x[1]);
            System.out.println("An Array Greater Added: " + Arrays.toString((int[]) x[1]));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowestPositions.get(0)));
        } else if((int) x[0] == totalValue) {
            System.out.println("An Array Equal Added: " + Arrays.toString((int[]) x[1]));
            lowestPositions.add((int[]) x[1]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowestPositions.get(0)));
    System.out.println(lowestPositions.size());
    System.out.println(totalValue);
    return lowestPositions.toArray(new int[lowestPositions.size()][]);
}
```

Here are some sample outputs (I am putting in the values for the matrix from terminal for now):

[image: Sample output]

Comment: what does mean by while((x = graphTraversal())[1] != null) ??? it will not be compile.

Comment: @Prashant `graphTraversal()` finds the next valid sequence and returns an array. The `1` index of that array contains the `int[]` that has the sequence values. So, I assign that array it gets from the call to `x` and then check if it's null. If it isn't null, which means that there is another valid sequence that it found, then the while loop is executed, otherwise it doesn't look for another sequence.

Comment: You're doing `lowestPositions.clear();` when new sequence is greater than `totalValue`, check on that part once

Comment: @Arkantos That was my intention. If the new sequence, which is the iteration it's on produces a greater total value than the previous one, I want to clear the List so I can add the new sequence, as the previous sequence is invalid. If the new sequence is equal to the previous one, then just add it to the list without clearing old one.

Comment: @Omoro.. why do you think it's incorrect ? ArrayList is a container for Objects, so even though `int` is primitive, `int[]` is an object, so it's still valid :)

Comment: @Abdul.. It's hard to reason about your code without knowing your intent, anyways can you add some possible test inputs and expected and actual outputs ? It would be helpful if you can give more details about your `Graph` class initialization as well

Comment: @Arkantos I wasn't able to add the sample run by text, but took a screenshot of it instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72554/discussion-between-arkantos-and-abdul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method private int[] getNextPositions() returns a reference to the same array all the time:
`int[] tempArray = positions;`

It seems to be the source of the problems.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to `int[] tempArray = positions.clone();` and it works perfectly now. So, from now on, when I refer to an instance variable within a method, I should be referring to a clone instead to be safe?

Comment: It depends on what are you doing with an instance variable. It is usually safer to work with immutable objects, but copying everything has its price. Sometimes it may be not efficient. Generally, if you want to return a value from a method, it is risky to return a reference to a field of the object and it's better to make a copy.